# Indentation of description lists

Tags: org-mode, indentation

`org-mode` automatically indents description lists, but it uses two different schemes. For short labels, the second line of the description is aligned with the first character of the description. For long labels, the second line of the description is indented to five spaces, regardless of the first line. e.g.:

```
- short label :: description description description description  
                 description description description description  

- very long label :: description description description description
     description description description description
```

This produces ugly formatting for lists with a mix of description lengths. How can I control this behaviour for consistent indenting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the variable `org-list-description-max-indent`. It's not documented in the manual, but its documentation string reads:

> Maximum indentation for the second line of a description list.
>   When the indentation would be larger than this, it will become
>   5 characters instead.

So we can force description list indentation to always be 5 spaces by setting the maximum to 5:

```
(setq org-list-description-max-indent 5)
```

This produces:

```
- short label :: description description description description
     description description description description

- very long label :: description description description description
     description description description description
```

Different values will shift the threshold that switches indenting between 5 spaces and aligning with the first line.

As far as I can tell, there is no built-in way to change the default indent - it's always 5 spaces.

Comment: As an aside: the 5 spaces appears to be hard-coded into `org-list-item-body-column`.  In the absence of a feature request to make this customizable, the workaround would be to redefine that function with a default size more to your liking.  (The function is about 20 lines long, FYI).

Comment: If you are using a newer version of org-mode (2019+) and ask yourself why the seconds line isn't indented as shown here: The fancy description list indentation got removed. Reason: Special indentation on description items breaks indentation in sub-items.